# How to fix first and last dataLabels on stacked grouped bar chart for ApexCharts

Tags: angular, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

When I create a stacked grouped bar chart the
[first and last dataLabels don't show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XopDZ.png).

Here is the configuration that I feel matters:

```
chart: {
    type: "bar",
    stacked: true,
    height: 400,
    zoom: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    toolbar: {
        show: false,
    },
},
colors: this.colors,
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    offsetY: -20,
    style: {
        colors: ["#000"],
    },
    formatter: (val: number, opts) => {
        if (opts.seriesIndex === 4) return estimatesTotals[opts.dataPointIndex];
        if (opts.seriesIndex === 2 || opts.seriesIndex === 3) return "";
        return val;
    },
},
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        dataLabels: {
            position: "top",
            hideOverflowingLabels: false,
        },
        hideZeroBarsWhenGrouped: false,
    },
},
xaxis: {
    categories: categories,
    type: "category",
    tickPlacement: "on",
}
```

If I change the tickPlacement to "between" the dataLabels show but all the  [columns get shifted to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9bCB.png) instead of being centered properly (you can see some of the bars overlapping the ticks):

If I add some characters to the dataLabels in the formatter, for example ".00" then it shows the dataLabels, but it seems to be dependent on the length of the string I add for it to show.